# electron + react + firebase enableIndexedDbPersistence show error prompt

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, electron

electron + react + firebase enableIndexedDbPersistence show error prompt, but working seems normal.

I don't have 10 reputation, so I can't post images, please click on the link, thank you very much for your efforts.

FYI.
error message as follow：

```
[2022-03-30T05:34:53.552Z]  
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.6.7): IndexedDbPersistence LocalStorage is unavailable. 
As a result, persistence may not work reliably. 
In particular enablePersistence() could fail immediately after refreshing the page.
```

[image: enter error detail image description here]

[image: enter normal indexeddb image description here]

Code as follow:

```
    this.app = initializeApp(firebaseAppConfig);
    this.firestoreDB = getFirestore(this.app);
    this.realtimeDB = getDatabase(this.app);
    const enableOffline = async () => {
      try {
        await enableIndexedDbPersistence(this.firestoreDB);
      } catch (err: any) {
        if (err.code == 'failed-precondition') {
          logger.error('failed-precondition', err);
          // Multiple tabs open, persistence can only be enabled
          // in one tab at a a time.
          // ...
        } else if (err.code == 'unimplemented') {
          logger.error('unimplemented', err);
          // The current browser does not support all of the
          // features required to enable persistence
          // ...
        } else {
          logger.error('unkown', err);
        }
      }
    };
    enableOffline();
```

Comment: Can you add english view of the attached screenshot?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, error messages, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @AkberIqbal Thank you comments. I haved updated english screenshot.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for your reminder! I have added error message. I just used Stack Overflow and am not very familiar with format